# Problem with ST_Intersection in postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have got a problem with ST_Intersection as bellow query. I do not know why I can not get element z of this intersection?

----query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection('LINESTRING Z (0 0 0, 2 2 2)',
                                 'LINESTRING Z (0 1 4, 1 0 4)'));
```

My result=
`"POINT(0.5 0.5)"`

My desire result= `"POINT Z (0.5 0.5 2.25)"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ST_3DIntersection](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersection.html) instead.

Comment: I know ST_3Dintersection with sfcgal backend is work truly, But I can not use it.

Comment: Your query actually works on my machine. Here's my config: `POSTGIS="2.1.2 r12389" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER`

Comment: It was worked already on my pc. It get error after I I changed Windows and now my config is: "POSTGIS="2.2.0dev r13206" GEOS="3.5.0dev-CAPI-1.9.0 r4046" SFCGAL="1.0.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" TOPOLOGY (topology procs from "2.1.5 r13152" need upgrade) RASTER"

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much... but it seems there is way too much "dev" versions in your setup. The issue might relate to the PostGIS version.

Comment: TNX @zimmi. I reinstall postgres and postgis. Fortunately, it work now And here is my config:
"POSTGIS="2.2.0dev r13206" GEOS="3.5.0dev-CAPI-1.9.0 r4046" SFCGAL="1.0.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" TOPOLOGY (topology procs from "2.1.5 r13152" need upgrade) RASTER"